# Pycharm : How to forcefully stop a server if it is already running

Tags: pycharm

Is there a way for me to tell pycharm that

> "start the debug server and if its already running then stop it and
>   run it again"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One for sure way if you are on Linux/Mac is to go to terminal and do `ps -eaf| grep python`. And kill the processes manually by `kill -9 <pid>`. ( where `<pid>` is the process id - number printed against the python process)

I don't use pycharm. I use sublime text. ST also has similar issues and I kill the python processes that go into unending while loops this way.

On Windows, stopping python.exe from task manager should do the trick.